# upgarde Ruby to 1.8.7 mac os 10.5

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to upgrade Ruby to 1.8.7 but I got problems ! 
I follow [this tutoriel](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard/) whith no success !
I tried to install RVM but with this command

> $ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)

I got an error :

> Missing name for redirect

I really don't understand how to tell the system to use ruby 1.8.7 ! 
I need to upgrade because I need to upgarde rails to version 3.

I already did a lot a search on stackoverflow, google but I'm stuck ! I don't find the solution !

Thanks to help me !

Answer (score 3):

You have a space between your two angle brackets (<<). Remove the space and the command will work.

As a side note, Ruby 1.8.7 is deprecated. Unless you have a specific need for the 1.8.x branch, Ruby 1.9.x should be your target.

*edit*

Make sure you have all the necessary tools installed. The script invokes `git` which you'll need to install.

Comment: I remove the space but I still get the error ! I don't get it ! I'm gonna try to install ruby 1.9.2 ! Thanks you !

Comment: Do you have git and curl installed?

Comment: oh no i don't have git installed ! Thanks !